# PHP if title contains $variable

Tags: php

I have my variable, `$mustcontain` and I have the following:

```
if ($getvideoviews >= $minimumvideoviews 
    AND $getvideolikes >= $minimumvideolikes 
    AND $VidDuration >= $minvidlenght 
    AND $getchannelsubscribers >= $minsubs)
```

What I need is to check if `$videotitle` contains what´s in `$mustcontain` and if true then proceed to show some more information

Comment: Take a look to `preg_match` : https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php

Comment: use `strpos($videotitle,$mustcontain) !== false`

Comment: is `$mustcontain` a string? an array? please add some details/code

Comment: $mustcontain = 'echo 'Hello';

Comment: @Minato it is not working, it returns like if $mustcontain would contain something that $videotitle doesnt

Comment: Fixed it, problem was on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

If `$mustcontain` is a string:

```
if ($getvideoviews >= $minimumvideoviews 
    && $getvideolikes >= $minimumvideolikes 
    && $VidDuration >= $minvidlenght 
    && $getchannelsubscribers >= $minsubs
    && strpos($videotitle, $mustcontain) !== false) {
        // do sth. with it
    }
```

If `$mustcontain` is an array:

```
if ($getvideoviews >= $minimumvideoviews 
    && $getvideolikes >= $minimumvideolikes 
    && $VidDuration >= $minvidlenght 
    && $getchannelsubscribers >= $minsubs
    && in_array($videotitle, $mustcontain) !== false) {
        // do sth. with it
    }
```

Comment: @CaseyChampney: Yes, you can, see my updated answer.

Comment: it doesnt return what i want, it returns whats inside }else{